# MySQL on JSON array and subquery issues

Tags: sql, mysql

Q: At present, I have the ID of `table_b`. How can I query the data corresponding to `table_a`?

###### table_a

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 |
| 2 | a2 |
| 3 | a3 |

###### table_b

| id | table_a_ids |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [1, 2] |
| 2 | [2, 3] |

It's not effective

```sql
select * from table_a where id in (select json_extract(batch_bill_ids, '$') from table_b where id = 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_a
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT NULL
   FROM table_b 
   WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(table_b.table_a_ids, CAST(table_a.id AS JSON))
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do a join using the [member of](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_member-of) operator as the following:

```
select a.id, a.value
from table_a a join table_b b
on a.id member of (b.table_a_ids)
where b.id = 1
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ki96T9wJ)